# how to fix div goes down when resizing window in jsp

Tags: jquery, css

I am developing game like match the following using jquery animate.Its working fine what i expected. But my problem is, I am displaying question and option in two div like below code,

```
    <div align="center">
    <div id="first" class="nav nav-justified">      
         <label id="Cat" class="dropzone">Cat</label><br><br><br>
         <label id="Snake" class="dropzone">Snake</label><br><br><br>
         <label id="Cow" class="dropzone">Cow</label><br><br><br>
     </div>
        <div id="second">
            <label id="Cow" class="item"  name="Milk">Milk</label><br><br><br>        
             <label id="Cat" class="item"  name="Rat">Rat</label><br><br><br>  
              <label id="Snake" class="item"  name="Eagle">Eagle</label><br><br><br>  
     </div>
 </div>
```

then making alignment using below css,

```
#first {

    float:left; /* add this */

    height: 350px;
     padding-left: 150px;
}
#second {

   float:left;
     height: 350px;
     padding-left: 250px;
}
```

When i resizing window that 2nd div automatically goes down and making unorder alignment.

Here is my problem : http://jsfiddle.net/Manivasagam/z4aLva34/27/

I dont know that much about css.Hope someone tell How to fix this?

Update : I want display like below image,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a container `div`, what has a `width` (or `min-width`) around your pairs.

```
.container {width: 400px; border: 1px solid #f00}
```

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z4aLva34/29/)**

For demonstration, I've just added a border to that container div.

Comment: check your jsfoddle, its not like display question and answer next and next.

Comment: check my question now, i want to display like that.

Comment: I checked, but i really don't understand. For those, you need to use iamges, and set the boxes width and height. But anyway, your original problem was this: `When i resizing window that 2nd div automatically goes down and making unorder alignment.` My solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you had `padding-left: 250px`

Instead of this I added

`text-align:left` and `float:right`

Check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z4aLva34/30/).

Comment: What? I didn't get what you said.

Comment: i meant resize the window after matched question and answer, its align is changing!, check in your jsfiddle.

Comment: check my question now i want to display that two div like that image.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of `padding-left: 250px` to the `#second` element. Remove that and give `padding-right: 250px;` to `#first` element.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/z4aLva34/31/)**